# How do I call SignalR in a chrome extension background page for specific host?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR in a chrome extension on a background page.

Everything seems to work fine until it tries to call negotiate.  It seems to be taking the caller (which is a chrome-extension background page) and trying to call negotiate against that, which gives me a 404 while trying to call this page:

`chrome-extension://edcdcfjmmmchhgmomfemdkomibeoloko/signalr/negotiate?_=1372007788595`

I'd imagine that it should be calling

`https://myserver.com/signalr/negotiate?_=1372007788595`

But I don't know how to override SignalR with a specific host.  Can I override SignalR to work in a chrome extension on a background page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is javascript you are using? Try

```
 $.connection.hub.url = "http://myserver.com/signalr";
```

Answer (score 1):

This took me a couple hours to figure out but here's a few steps to get going on making signalr work with a google chrome extension.

Place within the javascript

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://yoursever.com/signalr"`
```

Within the manifest.json file for the google chrome you must give permission to access the server. I would add something like this to make it easy.

```
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"
]
```

Within your global configuration you need to change allow cross domain requests. Change

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()
```

to

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration()
{
    EnableCrossDomain = true
});
```